# Jquey for-Loop - Função retorna "Cannot set property 'href' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando criar uma função que busque todos os links de uma `div` e encurte eles:

```
function encurtarUrl(){

        var conteudoPronto = document.getElementById("saida"); // armazena a DIV com id "saida"
        var numeroAProntos = conteudoPronto.getElementsByTagName("a").length; // conta o numero de 

        for (c=0; c < numeroAProntos; c++){

            $.getJSON( "http://is.gd/create.php?callback=?", {
                url: conteudoPronto.getElementsByTagName("a")[c].href,
                format: "json"
            }).done(function( data ) {
                urlEncurtada = data.shorturl;
                document.getElementById("saida").getElementsByTagName("a")[c].href = urlEncurtada; // subistitui o link antigo pelo encurtado
            });
        }

    }
```

Porém na linha `document.getElementById("saida").getElementsByTagName("span")[c].href = urlEncurtada;` Ele retorna: ***Cannot set property 'href' of undefined***

Código HTML:

```
<div id="saida"><br>
  *Título Noticia 1*<br>
  Texto noticia 1<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a><br>
  <br>
  *Titulo noticia 2*<br>
  Texto noticia 2<a href="http://www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a><br>
  <br>
  *Titulo Noticia 3*<br>
  Texto noticia 3<a href="http://www.twitter.com">www.twitter.com</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Na hora de escrever o código aqui eu errei, ali na linha "document.getElementById("saida").getElementsByTagName("span")[c].href = urlEncurtada;" o elemento que ele procura é "a" e não "span";

Comment: pode postar um trecho do HTML?

Comment: Olá Wesley! Dá uma olhada a essa outra pergunta que indiquei. Acho que estás a perder a referência do `c` por teres código assíncrono. Se não conseguires resolver diz aqui.

Comment: @Sergio Consegui resolver! Obrigado.